# "A disliking of" vs. "a disliking for"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I was having a conversation with a friend, telling him that over time, I've started to dislike a certain genre of music:

> I've grown a strong disliking for Dubstep.

As though my liking for Dubstep has gradually decreased over a set period of time. Now, I'm starting to question whether the use of *for* is correct. Have I grown a strong disliking *for* Dubstep, or have I grown a strong disliking *of* Dubstep? They both seem proper to me, but I'd like to be sure.

Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Try saying 'strong **dislike** for', instead.

Comment: Zolani13, Can I suggest waiting for a few more answers before accepting mine? There are some really smart cookies out there who provide good answers all day and night long. (Really, my feelings won't be hurt if you "unaccept" this.)

Comment: Sure, np. But it has been a while since the question launched, no? Is it okay now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think I would use the noun [*dislike*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dislike).

And then it seems to be a matter of whether you speak British English or talk American English. Compare [this NGram for American English:](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+strong+dislike+of%2Ca+strong+dislike+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3) 
[image]

and [this for British English:](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+strong+dislike+of%2Ca+strong+dislike+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3) 
[image]

---

Interestingly, if you remove the "a strong" from the search terms, you get [as Barrie England points out in his answer and zpletan in his comment], a more pronounced preference for *dislike of*, especially in British English. If you search for "a dislike of/for", adding the article *a*, *a dislike of* is still preferred but only by a slim margin in American English. (I didn't add those graphs, but you can create the NGram using the links provided.)

Compare this [NGram of dislike of/for in American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dislike+of%2Cdislike+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3)
[image]

And this [NGram of dislike of/for in British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dislike+of%2Cdislike+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3):
[image]

The bottom line is that *dislike of* is preferred, but both *dislike of* and *dislike for* are used, understandable, and mean the same thing. (That is, you are no longer fond of Dubstep.)

Comment: Do you prefer "dislike" over "a disliking" because it's simpler?

Comment: See the link to the definition of *dislike* I gave. I believe it is what you meant. (*Disliking* is the present participle of the verb *dislike*.)

Comment: The Ngrams results with less specific search terms are interesting. In both British and American English, "dislike of" beats "dislike for" by a wide margin. However, the results for "*a* dislike of/for" show that the two are about even overall and in AmE, but in BrE "of" still is more popular. As a whole, these results suggest that "of" is the "more correct" one. (However, as an American, I would use "for" in my own usage.)

Comment: Yes. I checked "dislike of/for" and "a dislike of/for" and saw what you mentioned, too. I decided to show the graphs with the phrases closer to the OP's wording.

Answer (score 1):

A search of the Corpus of Contemporary American English and the British National Corpus shows that *dislike* is much more frequent overall than *disliking* and that while BrEng and AmEng both show a strong preference for *dislike of* over *dislike for*, the preference is more pronounced in BrEng.